# Problema al convertir String a un numero entero y sacar modulo - PHP

Tags: php

tengo el siguiente problema, tengo varias variables numericas o de tipo string, pero siguen siendo numeros en la entrada, debo unir todas esas variables, lo mas facil , fue tratar todo como cadenas, y almacenar todos los datos concatenados en una variable a la que llamo $fullcad, al tener esta variable, o este "numero", debo de sacar el modulo 11 de todo ello, y ahi es mi problema, al parcear la cadena a numero ya sea de la forma $newvar= (int)($fullcad%11), o usando el método intval(), me da el valor de cero:

esta son mis funciones que voy haciendo, por el requerimiento de cliente, se llena N ceros a la izquierda algunas variables:

```
public function generateCUF($NumberNit, $FullDate, $NumberSuc, $TypeMod, $TypeEmit, $TypeDoc, $TypeSec, $NumberInvoice, $NumberPOS){
        //forNit
        //$NumberNit=$this->fillZeros( "".$NumberNit, 13-($this->nCharacters("".$NumberNit))  );
        //forsucursal
        $NumberSuc=$this->fillZeros( "".$NumberSuc, 4-($this->nCharacters("".$NumberSuc))  );
        //typesector
        $TypeSec=$this->fillZeros( "".$TypeSec, 2-($this->nCharacters("".$TypeSec))  );
        //for number of invoice
        $NumberInvoice=$this->fillZeros( "".$NumberInvoice, 8-($this->nCharacters("".$NumberInvoice))  );
        //for number of point to sale
        $NumberPOS=$this->fillZeros( "".$NumberPOS, 4-($this->nCharacters("".$NumberPOS))  );

        $fullCad=$NumberNit.$FullDate.$NumberSuc.$TypeMod.$TypeEmit.$TypeDoc.$TypeSec.$NumberInvoice.$NumberPOS;
        echo "cadena original-->".$fullCad;
        echo "<br>";
        $val1=(int) $fullCad;
        echo "valor con parseo int --> ".$val1;
        $val2= intval($fullCad);
        echo "<br>valor con parseo inval()--> ".$val2;
        echo "<br>";
        
        echo "Sacando modulo 11 directo del valor original quitando ceros que estan delante: 12345678920190113163721231000011101000000010000";
        echo "<br>el modulo es -->".((int)12345678920190113163721231000011101000000010000)%11;
        echo " el modulo deberia ser 3";
        //return [$fullCad=>$mod11];



    }
    private function nCharacters($var){
        return strlen($var);
    }
    private function fillZeros($var, $nZeros){
        for($i=0;$i<$nZeros;$i++){
            $var='0'.$var;
        }
        return $var;
    }
```

Y no me funciona, probando el valor:
12345678920190113163721231000011101000000010000
sacando el modulo 11 de ese numero en esta web:https://es.planetcalc.com/8326/
es correcto, me da como modulo 3, y es el valor correcto del ejemplo que da el cliente.

como llamo a la funcion y los parametros que proporciono? es este:

```
$this->generateCUF(123456789,20190113163721231,0,1,1,1,1,1,0);


estos son los resultados que me da en mi vista:
cadena original-->12345678920190113163721231000011101000000010000
valor con parseo int --> 9223372036854775807
valor con parseo inval()--> 9223372036854775807
Sacando modulo 11 directo del valor original: 12345678920190113163721231000011101000000010000
el modulo es -->0el modulo deberia ser 3
```

en terminal de laravel tinker, si pruebo sacar el modulo directo del valor mencionado, me da un mensaje:

```
>>> $val1=(12345678920190113163721231000011101000000010000)%11;
PHP Deprecated:  Implicit conversion from float 1.2345678920190113E+46 to int loses precision in Psy Shell code on line 1
```

pero si parseo con double, si me da todo el numero como quiero, pero me da nuevamente el error:

```
>>> $val2= (double)12345678920190113163721231000011101000000010000;
=> 1.234567892019E+46
>>> echo $val2%11;
PHP Deprecated:  Implicit conversion from float 1.2345678920190113E+46 to int loses precision in Psy Shell code on line 1
0⏎
```

Alguno se topó con este problema? que considero para dar solución?
version de php:

PHP 8.1.3 (cli) (built: Feb 21 2022 14:48:42) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.1.3, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v8.1.3, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies

Entorno de Sistema: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Comment: int es muy chico para ese numero... de ahi tu problema...

Comment: si, pero al parsearlo a double, no me funciona tampoco

Answer (score 1):

Lo resolví utilizando un método llamado [bcmod](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.bcmod.php) propio de php.

```
$result= bcmod($mystring, "numbertomodule");
```

Comment: Disculpame, ando familiarizándome con la plataforma :)